# Kernel panic can't exit

Tags: kernel

That's some errors I get. I'm trying to boot my laptop and get some work done before going to work tomorrow.

`VFS: Cannot open root device "sda1" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6`

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root FS on unknown-block(0,0)
```

Comment: The only thing I could do is to kill my battery and restart the system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your initramfs image may be corrupt, or missing. To recreate it, first check your file system for errors, and then run update-initramfs. Note that I've placed comments after each command that you don't need to type, it's just for your information.

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type:

  - `sudo fsck -f /` # check your file system for errors
  - `sudo mount -o rw,remount /` # remount your hard disk read/write mode
  - `sudo update-initramfs -c -k "$(uname -r)"` # recreate initramfs image
  - `sudo update-grub` # update the grub boot loader
  - `reboot` # to reboot the computer

## Update #1

- boot to the **-71** recovery mode, and at the root access # prompt, type:

  - `sudo mount -o rw,remount /`
  - `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 4.4.0-72-generic` **# note the -72**
  - `sudo update-grub`
  - `reboot` **# then use the normal Ubuntu boot choice in GRUB**

## Update #2

- boot into whatever recovery mode that you can, prefer -72 or -71
- `sudo mount -o rw,remount /`
- `ls -al /etc/cryp*`

  - if you see any cryp* files, then `cat /etc/cryp{the complete name here}`
- `ls -al /etc/fstab`
- `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

  - arrow keys to move cursor
  - control-o to save changes
  - control-x to quit pico
- change this line: `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0`

  to this: `#/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0`

  - save and quit pico
- `reboot` (try booting either -72 or -71 kernels)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56912/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-kernel-panic-cant-exit).